# How to clear DNS Cache/Fix DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN (Manjaro + Vivaldi)

Tags: linux, dns, cache

I am recently getting the DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN error browsing with Vivaldi (based on Chromium) running on Manjaro Linux (based on Arch). I have read that this error mainly has to do with DNS Cache and clearing it will fix this issue. I couldn't figure out however how to do this with Manjaro, I am not even sure if Manjaro manages a DNS cache by default. Restarting fixes the problem, but that's quite a cumbersome. Based on proposed solutions for other linuxes I tried the following without success:

- `sudo /etc/init.d/dns-clean  # /etc/init.d/ not found`
- `sudo systemctl restart nscd  # no error, no effect as well`

`nscd` is installed however. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I think there are two places you can check.

#### nscd

You can flush the nscd cache by invalidating the hosts cache:

`nscd -i hosts`

You can then check for the current number of cached values if you're curious:

`nscd -g`

#### Vivaldi

You can also clear Vivaldi's cache:

`vivaldi://net-internals/#dns`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sry for the late answer, back when I asked a reboot fixed the issue for me. It is however appearing again and rebooting is cumbersome. Trying out your solutions didn't do the trick. Flushing with `sudo nscd -K; sudo nscd` also doesn't give the desired effect. Also, my feeling is that now the amount of inaccessible sites is not as big as then, e.g. I needed to access su.sx via another device on the last occasion, which I can now access just fine.

Answer (score 0):

**For Ubuntu**

These errors indicate that there is some problem with DNS.

- check `cat /etc/resolv.conf` for your DNS settings.
- And add following name server in  `/etc/resolv.conf` for temporary or in `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head` for permanent

> ```
> nameserver 8.8.8.8
> nameserver 8.8.4.4
> ```

- To add these two name server address in `resolv.conf`

  - run command `sudo gedit /etc/resolv.conf`
  - Copy above two line of nameserver paste on last line of `resolv.conf`
  - Ctrl+S to save.
- Note: If you add name server only `/etc/resolv.conf` then when computer is restarted then `/etc/resolv.conf` is in previous stage.
  So, to store these nameservers permanently, use following method :

  - run command `sudo gedit /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head`
  - Copy above two lines of nameserver and paste on last line of `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head`
  - Ctrl+S to save.
- Re-connect internet connection

More Detail On https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_Debugging#DNS_Servers

**For Windows:**

- Add these DNS ip on network configuration
- Tutorial to add DNS in windows is here
  https://www.opennicproject.org/configure-your-dns/how-to-change-dns-servers-in-windows-7/
- Re-connect internet connection